# Search ElasticSearch / Nest - Address Suggestion Api with Category Filter

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, search-suggestion

The user who calls my Rest API must be able to specify the type of place and then have a placename suggestion.

The placetype must be exact while the placename search uses all the potential of the elaticsearch search.

I'm using NEST (latest nuget version) and Elastic 6.4.

My Api has 2 parameters:
1. query: search text search
2. placetypes: array to define the desired "categories" of documents in the suggestion

The placename suggestion with the Query parameter works well, 
but I do not know how to add the condition of placetype.

Nest Mapping :

```
return map
  .Dynamic(false)
  .Properties(props => props
    .Keyword(n => n
      .Name(p => p.Id))
    .Text(n => n
      .Name(p => p.PlaceType))
    .Completion(n => n
      .Name(p => p.PlaceName)
      .Analyzer("autocompletion_indexation"))
    .Completion(n => n
      .Name(p => p.Address)
      .Analyzer("autocompletion_indexation"))
    .GeoPoint(loc =>
      {
      loc.Name(location => location.Coordinates);
      return loc;
      }));
```

Nest AnalysisDescriptor :

```
return analysis
    .CharFilters(c => c
        .HtmlStrip("html_strip")
    )
    .Tokenizers(t => t
        .EdgeNGram("custom_ngram", descriptor =>
            {
            descriptor.MinGram(2);
            descriptor.MaxGram(10);
            descriptor.TokenChars(new List<TokenChar> { TokenChar.Letter, TokenChar.Digit });
            return descriptor;
            }
        ))
    .TokenFilters(tf => tf
        .Lowercase("lowercase")
        .WordDelimiter("word_delimiter", wd =>wd
        .SplitOnNumerics()
        .SplitOnCaseChange()
    )
    .AsciiFolding("asciifolding", af => af
        .PreserveOriginal(false)
    )
    .Elision("elision", e => e
        .Articles("l", "d", "o")
    )
    .Synonym("address_synonym", sy => sy
        .Synonyms(GetSynonyms())
        .Tokenizer("standard")
        .Tokenizer("whitespace")
    )
    .Stop("french_stop", fs => fs
        .StopWords("_french_"))
    .Stemmer("french_stemmer", fs => fs
    .Language("light_french")
)
)
    .Analyzers(an => an
        .Custom("autocompletion_indexation", c => c
        .Tokenizer("custom_ngram")
        .Tokenizer("standard")
        .Tokenizer("whitespace")
        .CharFilters("html_strip")
        .Filters("address_synonym",
        "lowercase",
        "asciifolding",
        "elision",
        "word_delimiter",
        "stop",
        "french_stemmer",
        "french_stop")
));
```

Suggest/Search function:

```
public Task<List<Place>> SuggestDocuments(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string query, params string[] placeTypes)
{
var search = new SearchDescriptor<Place>()
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Index(PlaceDataService.DefaultPostalAddressIndexName)
    .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
        .Query(query)
        .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
        .Fields(fields => fields
            .Field(f => f.PlaceName)
            )));

var searchResults = _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Place>(search, cancellationToken);
return Task.Run(() => searchResults.Result.Documents.ToList(), cancellationToken);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the `multi_match` query with a `terms` query, by wrapping them in a `bool` query to achieve this

```
var query = "this is the place name";
var places = new [] { "Place 1", "Place 2" };

var search = new SearchDescriptor<Place>()
    .From(0)
    .Size(10)
    .Index("index")
    .Query(q => q
        .MultiMatch(mm => mm
            .Query(query)
            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
            .Fields(fields => fields
                .Field(f => f.PlaceName)
            )
        ) && +q
        .Terms(t => t
            .Field(f => f.PlaceType)
            .Terms(places)
        )
    );

var searchResults = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Place>(search, cancellationToken);
```

The above makes use of operator overloading for queries, which you can read more about in the [Writing Bool queries docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html). The above produces the following request

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "this is the place name",
            "fuzziness": "AUTO",
            "fields": [
              "placeName"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "placeType": [
              "Place 1",
              "Place 2"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that a `terms` query will **OR** the terms so that only at least one needs to match. If all inputs need to match, you can and multiple `term` queries together.

A few things don't look quite right with your mapping and analysis

1. `PlaceName` is mapped as a [`completion` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) but is being used in a `multi_match` search query, rather than a `suggest` search. I would have expected it to be mapped as a `text` datatype for this case.
2. If `PlaceType` fields need to be matched *exactly* as is, I would expect them to be mapped as [`keyword` datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html)
3. `html_strip` char filter is built in, so doesn't need to be re-specified, unless you need to customise how it works e.g. [`escaped_tags`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html). Similarly for `lowercase` token filter.
4. The `"autocompletion_indexation"` custom analyzer can only have one tokenizer, so the last assigned wins (`"whitespace"` tokenizer). Check out the [writing analyzers docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-analyzers.html).